# PAYPAL C# SDK missing

Tags: c#, sdk, paypal

Hi besides having spent the last three evenings trying to find out why my IPN handler has stopped wworking on all my websites (best I can work out is some file write permissions maybe) but yet to find the answer I have also yet to find the C# SDK samples for any of the payment methods Classic API, Rest API, etc. Do they exist?

I hate to say it but the more I try to read the Paypal dev site the more im considering using a different payment method for my customers, i've never wasted so much time trying to find information on something and hit the same no help link many times.

Trev.

Comment: Thanks for the mark down, seems some people don't like feedback on their work....

Comment: Just wondering if anything has been done or an acknowledgement that there may or may not be a problem with the IPN simulator? As today I have tried again to use the IPN simulator on one of my sites that 1) used to work with the IPN simulator and 2) actually is still receiving orders from Paypal purchases and talking to the exact file the IPN simulator won't. It just returns "IPN Delivery Failed:protocol = http host = null". Yet, like I said, im getting IPN info. that I write to my database and its fine.

Comment: Another thing is I read a post about IPN only works to port:80, im not an expert on servers so not sure how you set up the IPN to talk to port:80 on a server (or is it the server listens on port:80?). cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK and Samples are all available here. Please download and use them and incase you run into any issues with your integration please open issues in the respective github repos.

http://paypal.github.io

Comment: Thank you for the link, its not working in Google Chrome (paypal.github.io/#button-manager-tab-csharp only allows me to download the Ruby version). Im running the latest one too 'Version 29.0.1547.57 m' – Plus tried IE 8, which also only allows Ruby download too plus clicking on the ".Net" tab move me down one too many sections. thanks.

Comment: Yes you are correct, looks like it doesn't navigate to the .NET Tab straight away. Use https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/raw/gh-pages/rest-api-sdk/dotnet/rest-api-sdk-dotnet-0.7.3.zip for downloading the SDK as zip.

Comment: Thank you, most appreciated. Seems it depends on the browser used too.